# Is it possible to generate a request scope?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using a request scoped bean in my application:

```
@Bean
@RequestScope
public BeanA beanA(){
   return new BeanA();
}
```

And, as long as I get web requests it is fine.
Problem is that I'm now supporting also other sources of request (for example Spring data redis listener) but, when I want to populate it with values I get

```
no thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

Would it possible to create a request scope?

Comment: Request scope is bound to your http request. If there is no http request, you cannot get a bean bound to that scope. May be update your question with what other kinds of request, you want to handle. In that case, you can create a custom scope that not only works for `httpRequest` but for your other types of `request`

Comment: If you want to use a bean inside of a request-scope Bean you can you the scope "prototype" for the other Bean. "prototype" creates a new instance, every time the Bean is injected

Comment: I need to create the beanA each time I receive an event on a redis event bus

Comment: @Phate beanA should be @Scope("prototype"). But important is also your event handler. If your event handler is created once, you should autowire the (Spring) ApplicationContext and call getBean(beanA) to get a new instance each time you need a beanA.

Comment: Why does it need to be a bean? It will be useful if you can give more context. Build a more detailed example of your use-cases